# Extended Activity class, nullpointer on init

Tags: android, interface, nullpointerexception

I want all my activities to have knowledge about the power state: is there a charger connected? When the registered receiver receives an `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` or an `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED` a callback to the activity is made to inform the registered activity. Since I want all activities that are part of the application, and I work with this callback method I created an interface which forces the activity to implement `powerDisconnected()` and `powerConnected();`

```
public interface BrightnessActivityInterface {
    void powerDisconnected();
    void powerConnected();
}
```

Because my activities all use the same type of code (eg. screen on and bright lock when connected, and screen dim when power is disconnected) I extended the `class Activity` and implemented the `BrightnessActivityInterface`:

```
public class BrightnessActivity extends Activity implements BrightnessActivityInterface {

    private ChargingOffReceiver chargingOff;
    private ChargingOnReceiver chargingOn;

    public BrightnessActivity(){
        chargingOn = new ChargingOnReceiver(this);
        registerReceiver(chargingOn, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED));


        chargingOff = new ChargingOffReceiver(this);
        registerReceiver(chargingOff, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED));
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }

    public void powerDisconnected() {
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }

    public void powerConnected() {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    }
```

All my activities extend now this BrightnessActivity instead of Activity. Sounds all good so far?

The problem is the first activity I start I get a nullpointer just after the line

```
 registerReceiver(chargingOn, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED));
```

'this' has a value (it is my launch activity), and chargingOn is a ChargingOnReceiver. I installed the source but I have no idea what I am looking at.

My class has the rights to register to the `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` and it worked fine until I derived all my classes from `BrightnessActivity` instead of Activity. Please advice.

Comment: The `Context` of an `Activity` is valid starting with its `onCreate` method. Your code has other flaws as well.

Comment: Using a constructor of an activity shows some deeper issues with you basic android understanding.

Comment: @WarrenFaith, do you mean that the activity is not yet a complete activity when it arrives in my constructor? The activity should be complete when my constructor is called.

Comment: @luksprog can you point out some of the other flaws?

Comment: @Harmen check this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: 1. You don't have any reasons to use the constructor of the Activity(use instead the lifecycle methods of the Activity) 2. related to the receivers, register them in the `onCreate`/`onResume` method 3. You never unregister the receivers so you risk memory leaks(check the documentation of the `BroadcastReceiver` class)

Comment: Wait. I see. lol. I was mixing up onCreate and the constructor. Thanks for helping out guys! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should register your receivers in `onCreate` and unregister in `onPause`

API: [onRegisterReceiver API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29)

> "You can either dynamically register an instance of this class with
>   Context.registerReceiver() or statically publish an implementation
>   through the tag in your AndroidManifest.xml. Note: If registering a
>   receiver in your Activity.onResume() implementation, you should
>   unregister it in Activity.onPause(). (You won't receive intents when
>   paused, and this will cut down on unnecessary system overhead). Do not
>   unregister in Activity.onSaveInstanceState()."

If you don't understand why your Activity isn't in a 'ready' state after the constructor, you'll need to do some reading on the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Answer (score 1):

You should not override default Activity constructor. Move your code to overriden onCreate() method.

Comment: No he can override the default constructor, he just can't register his receiver there. It is fine to instantiate your own objects there

Comment: Activity is never instantiated directly by new Activity(). So what's the point of constructor overriding?

Comment: For testing and dependency injection

Comment: Activity is part of Android Framework. Android creates the activity, initializes it. When activity object is created, system starts lifecycle with calling onCreate(). Any call to "this", or activity's method before calling onCreate() is risky.